# Security implications of storing client-side generated passphrase in chrome.storage.local

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've read through the documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) which warns about the danger of storing secure information in chrome.storage.local since it is unencrypted.

For my [application](https://github.com/loon3/LTB-Companion/), the extension generates a passphrase for the user locally using a Javascript library packaged with the extension.  That passphrase is then stored in chrome.storage.local and is never passed to a remote server via the extension.  I understand there are security implications because this is unencrypted and the application is still under development.  The purpose of this post is to discover the best security scheme possible.

The specific questions are...

- What are the methods (attack vectors) one can employ to access chrome.storage.local outside of the extension itself?
- Besides the risk of the client running the extension being compromised
  by a malicious script or application locally, is there a risk of a
  remote attack?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying about the passphrase.  It sounds to though like it would be better not to store it at all, and instead to store a salted hash of it, i.e. the same way websites "store" passwords.

Comment: The passphrase is not a password in the traditional sense.  It's actually a 12-word mnemonic seed used to generate ECC key pairs and is not convenient to have to remember and type in every time.  I've been doing some more reading and I'm planning on using AES encryption via the [crypto-js library](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/).  Specifically, the Cipher Output example.  The user can then create a traditional password to encrypt the passphrase.

Comment: **Bounty note:** Different SO questions list different methods in which the data could be attacked; the answers are a bit scattered. Hence I request for a single list containing all such methods in which the data could be attacked. Also, though not in the original question, please include `chrome.sync` vulnerabilites as well.

Comment: Just for pointer and something to consider when you save sensitive data to local storage or session storage. We have this kind of structure where  JWT secret is saved on server and we request it from server then use it to make JWT token with payload that we wan't to save. We can then again decode JWT token when needed and use it's payload. Saving plain text in browser with sensitive data is always a *NO GO* in my opinion.

Comment: I think you are probably asking the wrong question.  Securing the information with a user key phrase is one way to make your store more secure, but if you are worried about people who may gain access to your client device, you also need to make sure your key phrases aren't easily findable in caches, etc.  It gets to be a rathole quickly. 

I don't store anything important in the client and don't really trust anything I get back from it.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone with physical access can read the contents of the chrome.storage.local, however by design there is no way <del>for another extension to access the data from your extension, or</del> for a malicious site to directly access the data.

It is not impossible though - there could be some [zero-day](https://www.google.com/search?q=zero+day) vulnerability that allows this to occur.

There is always some risk of remote attack that results in control of the device.  Once this occurs, the same answer as above applies, i.e. someone with control of the device can read the local storage.

Its worth noting that Chromebooks have better protection against the above in that the underlying device storage may in fact be encrypted, and the attack surface for gaining direct access to that storage is very small.  However, other devices do not have these protections.

Comment: There _is_ a possibility for an extension to access someone else's `chrome.storage`. Specifically, extensions that create Dev Tools panels can access `chrome.storage` if opened on an extension page. See [Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb?hl=en) for an example.

Comment: Interesting, so would it be possible for a malicious extension to send the chrome.storage data from all extensions installed on the local machine to a remote server?  Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Data stored in `chrome.storage.local` is not encrypted in any way, thus can be read as plain-text.

There are a lot of methods to access this data, whether through some other "high-priviledged" chrome extensions (like those with access to dev-tools) or from any other process (in case they have the right permission, which varies through different OS) running on the client's machine, by access directly to the files where chrome stores this data.

To answer your second question, you need to understand first, how your data is transferred and how your application built. If there is a targeted attack toward your application, it depends on the backdoor or any other security flaws in your extension that might lead for an unauthorized access to client's extension. It is all depends on the time, effort and interest of the hacker - For the sake of the example, if you are storing a sensitive bank access credentials in this storage, then most likely, it will significantly increase the interest of the hacker, which he will then spend more time and effort to trying access this storage on as many client's as possible.
Furthermore, if the the hacker have access to client's files, regardless to your specific application, then all files on the client's computer are compromised, including your extension's storage data.

I am strongly suggesting, not to store any sensitive data in client-side application (extension), but store it on a server-side, where the chances of this data being compromised are much lower.
If you still need to use this data on the client side, make sure to:

1. Pass only a relevant data every time the extension need to use it. Data that is not used, must not be transferred.
2. Pass the data encrypted with a key that can be stored in client's storage. The key should be a randomly generated key on each client, in order to prevent mass extraction, once one client's key has been compromised. Yes, this is still opened for targeted attack on your application, but covers the chance of the data being stolen with non-targeted attacks.
3. Never store this encrypted nor decrypted data in any kind of storage in clients machine (incl. cookies, local storage, session storage, global variables, etc.).

But I would not suggest to pass the data to the client-side if you afraid that your data may be compromised, but do whatever you need to do on the server-side. This may force you to re-design the application, which is the only option in most of the cases.

Good luck!